# jQuery detect form changes

Tags: jquery, forms

Hope to get a little help from you guys.

Im using this script when detecting if a form has changed or not. If so, when I click a href link with a certain class a confirm window will popup.

```
var formChanged = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#my_form input[type=text].editable, #my_form textarea.editable').each(function (i) {
  $(this).data('initial_value', $(this).val());
});

$('#my_form input[type=text].editable, #my_form textarea.editable').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('initial_value')) {
       handleFormChanged();
}
});

$('#my_form .editable').bind('change paste', function() {
  handleFormChanged();
});

$('.navigation_link').bind("click", function () {
  return confirmNavigation();
});
});

function handleFormChanged() {
 $('#save_or_update').removeAttr('disabled');
 formChanged = true;
}

function confirmNavigation() {
 if (formChanged) {
      return confirm('Are you sure? Your changes will be lost!');
 } else {
      return true;
 }
}
```

Everything works fine, except for when i have a link inserted into a div on a buttonclick with jQuery like this (making the link "visible"):

```
$("button").click(function () {
  var dylink = "<a href='#' class='navigation_link'>dynammic link</a>";
  $("#tester").html(dylink);
});
```

the confirm window does not pop up if I edit the form and then click the "dynamic link".
The other link works perfect. Any idea what it could be?

This is the html code

```
<div><button>Show link</button></div>
<div id="tester"></div>
<div><a href="#" class="navigation_link">permanent link</a></div>
<form action="" method="get" id="my_form">
<input type="text" class="editable">
 <input type="button" name="button" id="save_or_update" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Thanks
/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers hinted at it, but explicitly, here's what to do.

Change this:

```
$('.navigation_link').bind("click", function () {
  return confirmNavigation();
});
});
```

to this:

```
$('.navigation_link').live("click", function () {
  return confirmNavigation();
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing object's innerHTML (which is what happens when you use `.html(...)`) may force the browser to recreate the some objects. The newly created objects may not have your event listeners bound. Therefore you should consider using `.live(...)` instead of `.bind(...)` for all the *change* events. See jQuery documentation on `.live` for more information.

Comment: Hey!! That worked perfectly. Thanks alot. Will read more about .live.

 Btw. Is this a good way of checking if a form has changed, so that i can get a confirm window before leaving the page? I found the script on the web and Im a beginner when i comes to js/jQuery.

Comment: @Andreas: it's good enough. You could optimize it by instead of `#my_form input[type=text].editable, #my_form textarea.editable` using just `#my_form .editable` and instead of binding to `keyup` or `paste` bind just to `change`. You'd get less (and simpler) code and achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("button").live("click",function () {
  var dylink = "<a href='#' class='navigation_link'>dynammic link</a>";
  $("#tester").html(dylink);
});
```